# Best practices to name Matrix fields handles

Tags: craft3

About matrix block fields handles: should they be unique ?

For instance if I have a matrix with handle `galleryMatrix`,
than should I name my block `galleryMatrixImage` or just `image`?
And than my fields in my block: `galleryMatrixImageName`, `galleryMatrixImageAsset` or `name` and `asset`?

I'm not quite sure about how to manage these handles the proper way?

I would prefer being able to name them with short handles, but i'm not sure if they have to be unique within a block, or unique for a whole website ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They only have to be unique within a block. So your initial idea would be best. 
Have a `galleryMatrix` field with an `image` block and fields with handles `imgName` and `imgAsset`.

I don't think you can use `name` as a handle, because it is a reserved word. `Asset` may be possible.